# Adding muliple field in the same table using postgresql and codeigniter and php

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I have a table that has a column llb, md and masters(all integers). I want to get their sum and store it to the column Total(same table). BTW im using codeigniter and postgresql and php. Any suggestions?

I want the column Total to be updated whenever i put a data on these columns.

Comment: do you any specific reasons why you want to store the sum in another column. If your always want sum of these columns, you can run a simple sql query to get that result

Comment: I know the query but i dont know where to put the code. I'm still learning about this topic specially the codeigniter

Comment: Then you need to learn the framework/languages first, just read the documentation. It will help you in longer run.

Comment: While you can do this with triggers, I strongly recommend using a *view* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing sum in another column is not good practice. Because column values may get changed. So you have to run update query again. Anyway answer for your question is :

```
update your_table set total = ( COALESCE(iib,0) + COALESCE(md,0), COALESCE(masters,0));
```

Comment: Well, actually, i want them to be updated whenever I add a data to these columns. Silly me, for not being specific. Sorry.

Comment: Then add values before insert. then you can directly insert with sum.

Comment: did you check the query? what about the result?